# Make function fire only once after spamming button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash, debouncing

I'm kinda piggybacking off a question I asked earlier.  But in the following piece of code, I want to be able to click this button multiple times but then fire the function only once.  I tried using a `setTimeout` but the function will still fire multiple times after the delay. Next, I've tried `debounce` from lodash, but this is just behaving exactly the same what as the `setTimeout`  Have I missed something in my code?

```
    const handler = debounce(() => {
    myFunction(name, age)
}, 1000);

function update() {
    handler();
}

        <StyledQuantityButton disabled={ amount <= 0 } 
            onClick={() => {
                const newValue = amount - 1;
                setAmount(newValue); 
                update();
            }} >
            &mdash;
        </StyledQuantityButton>
```

Comment: Why are you calling setAmount(newValue) outside of the handler? Isn't setAmount(newValue) the main action you're trying to take when you click the button? Try putting that setAmount() call in the debounced handler.

Comment: I have it this way because the user can visually see the amount change as they click.  If I have the setAmount in the debounce, the number won't update visually

Answer (score 1):

While you might have put the `myfunction(name, age)` part in debounce, your `setAmount` part is still outside the debounce.

Depending on how your component re-renders, the debounced function might also get recreated (therefore losing its "I just got called" status), which would lead to the same problem. Try this:

```js
const handler = React.useMemo(() => debounce(() => {
    setAmount(amount => amount - 1); 
    myFunction(name, age);
}), [myFunction]);

// ...
onClick={handler}
```

Comment: Hmm, this sets my amount value immediately to 0 no matter what value it is to begin with

Comment: @DonegalBoyVancouver Ah I didn't realize that because of the debounce and memo, the `amount` field would be stale. I've edited so `setAmount` gets called with a state mutator. In that case it shouldn't matter if the debounced function has stale data, since the mutator works in fresh data.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the user can visually see the amount change as they click. If I have the setAmount in the debounce, the number won't update visually right?

Comment: It should. The `setAmount` changes the component state, triggering it to re-render with the updated value. The `useMemo` just makes it that `handler` stays the exact same function (with debounce state) between renders.

Comment: Oh right ok.  The number is updating, but now it's immediately setting to 1

Comment: By default, the amount is set to 1.  When the component is loaded, it checks if the amount needs to be updated to a new value.   I think maybe the `useMemo` is pulling in the default value?

Comment: `setAmount(amount => amount - 1)` uses whatever the actual state is, e.g. what `amount` is in your `const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(defaultValue)`.

Comment: Hmm, the amount is only changing once per debounce (I click the button multiple times, visually, the number only changes by 1) then 1 is the amount set.  I think I have to modify the amount value outside the debounce, because it keeps getting the default (stale) value

Comment: in this codepen for example, https://codepen.io/mystroken/pen/Moraab.  What I'm trying to do is get the function to fire after the user has clicked the + or - quickly to get their required number.  The function would then do something with that number they select.  An issue I'm having is that I'm setting the amount if another condition is met, not just with the initial `const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(defaultValue)`.  Thanks so much for your help with this.  I'm kinda struggling with this.  This codepen isn't using hooks though

Comment: I assume you want to transform that codepen to a functional component? Not sure what the debounce part comes in play though.

Comment: Yeah.  I assumed a debounce is what I needed in this case.  Perhaps not?  In a nutshell, it would be;  Select a value, then a function does something with that value, but only fire once, not for every click.  It kinda sounded like what a debounce would do.  Unless there's a simpler way?  It's possible that I'm overthinking this haha.  Even in this case, can strip it down for the codepen, how would I go about firing a console log of the value when I've finished selecting a quantity?